# Let's get critical: Sep 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [English Language Learners Stack Exchange](http://ell.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://ell.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- ["had they known" or "if they had known"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9363/had-they-known-or-if-they-had-known)

  **Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [why no article before G.D.P.?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8702/why-no-article-before-g-d-p)

  **Net Score: -5** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 7)
- [What is the opposite of real-time?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8762/what-is-the-opposite-of-real-time)

  **Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Is America "it" or "she"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9068/is-america-it-or-she)

  **Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [What does 'be done' mean?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9132/what-does-be-done-mean)

  **Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [What does "be to" mean?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/what-does-be-to-mean)

  **Net Score: 9** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Is this an abbreviated form?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8678/is-this-an-abbreviated-form)

  **Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [How to describe the walk of a man with an artificial leg?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8735/how-to-describe-the-walk-of-a-man-with-an-artificial-leg)

  **Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Which is correct here, have or has?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9167/which-is-correct-here-have-or-has)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 1)
- ["It is to be questioned" versus "it has to be questioned"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9226/it-is-to-be-questioned-versus-it-has-to-be-questioned)

  **Net Score: -7** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 7)